Open SCAP (oscap) XPath error on RHEL9
Notes:
The below command will run for a while, then error out. I have not had a chance to reboot the server yet. It will create the arf.xml, but it does not create the report.html. Does anyone have any suggestions?
General Specs:
OSCAP Version = 1.3
OS = RHEL 9.3
Free Mem = 173GB, Free SWAPMEM = 3GB
CPU = Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6238 CPU @ 2.10GHz
Mount Free space 17GB
Command:
oscap xccdf eval \
 --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_stig \
 --results-arf arf.xml \
 --report report.html \
/usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-rhel9-ds.xml

Error:
XPath error : Memory allocation failed : growing nodeset hit limit
growing nodeset hit limit
^
runtime error: file /usr/share/openscap/xsl/xccdf-report.xsl line 91 element value-of XPath evaluation returned no result.
OpenSCAP Error: Could not apply XSLT /usr/share/openscap/xsl/xccdf-report.xsl to XML file: arf.xml [/builddir/build/BUILD/openscap-1.3.8/src/source/xslt.c:182]

Please set an environment variable as OSCAP_PROBE_MAX_COLLECTED_ITEMS=1000 it should work.

Thank you for this, it did it.
